# Radio button validation in React for dynamic number of radio buttons

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation

I have the following React component:

```
import React from 'react';
import classes from './surveytwo.css';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';


const surveyTwo = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className={ classes.screen2 } >

            <table className={ classes.initial__survey__details__table }>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Gender    
                        </td>
                        <td>
                             Age    
                        </td>     
                    </tr>     
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="radio" name="customer_gender" />                                     
                            <label>Male</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="radio" name="customer_name" />                                   
                            <label>Less than 35</label>
                        </td>     
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="radio" name="customer_gender" />                                    
                            <label>Female</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="radio" name="customer_name" />                                    
                            <label>More than 35</label>
                        </td>     
                    </tr> 
                    <tr>
                        <td colSpan="2">
                            {/* <button className={ [classes.btn , classes["btn--fullwidth"] , classes.btn__next  ].join(' ') }>NEXT</button> */}
                            <Link to="/" className={ [classes.btn , classes["btn--fullwidth"] , classes.btn__next  ].join(' ') }>
                                Survey 1
                            </Link>
                        </td>   
                    </tr>     
                </tbody>   
            </table>

        </div>
    );
}

export default surveyTwo;
```

As you can see there are 2 groups of radio buttons and a `Link` route that routes back to the homepage. I want both these radio button groups to be checked before the `Link` is enabled and the user can click on it, as of now the user can navigate away from this page with/without checking the radio buttons. How can I add this validation ?

Also the radio buttons can increase from 2 groups to a lot more in the future, so how do I go about adding this validation check and disabling the `Link` to the homepage until all the radio buttons are checked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Went through a quick draft, maybe not the best solution but hope it helps with the logic behind.

You could store the state of the radio buttons in the state of the component:

```
state = {
   genderRadioClicked: false,
   ageRadioClicked: false
   // Add any extra group you create later
}
```

And update it to true with the onChange event from the *input* using *setState*.

The validation method will look like this:

```
_handleRadioValidation = (e) => {

   // Get the state of all the radio buttons
   const radioStates = this.state

   // Iterate through the radio state object and return the value for 
   // every key and assign it to an array
   const checkedStatus = Object.keys(radioStates).map((key) => {
      return radioStates[key];
   });

   // Once you got the array with the value of the group radios (if 
   // the group is checked or not) filter the array to return only if the 
   // value is equal to false (which means that it's not checked)
   const filteredArray = checkedStatus.filter((value) => value === false)

   // If the length of the resulting array from the filtering is bigger
   // than 0 it means one of the group is false (unchecked)
   // Then you just prevent the default behaviour of the event, in this
   // case that is a link, it will disable the link.
   if (filteredArray.length > 0) {
      e.preventDefault();
      return;
   }

   // If all of them are checked it will execute like normal

}
```

Finally attach this method to the  component like this:

```
<Link to="/" onClick={(e) => this._handleRadioValidation(e)}>
```

Hope it helps!